# Remap alphabetic keys to numeric when NumLock is On with AutoHotKey

Tags: autohotkey

I have a laptop DELL XPS 13 9310 that doesn't come with physical or togglable numeric keys and visible NumLock key. However, I have just [discovered](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start-win_general/what-are-these-mysterious-fnkey-functions/709cf845-c84e-4bd2-a3d5-e0c656a37ac7) that I can press `Fn+B` to toggle the NumLock state as can be seen on a virtual keyboard.

Can AHK detect the NumLock state and rewrite `M JKL UIO` to `0 123 456`?
And how do I write this detection mechanism?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I woul'd try something like:

```
#Persistent
#if GetKeyState("NumLock", "T") 
    ToolTip % GetKeyState("NumLock", "T")
    M::
    Send, 0
        return
    J::
    Send, 1
        return
    K::
    Send, 2
        return
    L::
    Send, 3
        return
    U::
    Send, 4
        return
    I::
    Send, 5
        return
    O::
    Send, 6
        return
```

This is a bit grost, but, probably will do the job

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. Moreover, anything defined after this script appears to have stopped working too - like if there is a syntax error and it invalidates the remainder of the file?
/edit I learned that I can use `#If` behind the block to terminate the "context sensitivity". That said, the keys still don't work.

Comment: By following the documentation, I found that the key emits `Pause` signal instead. However, as seen on the gif above, the virtual keyboard still changes the NumLock state, although now I think it might be only internal to the keyboard and not the system as this `Pause::ToolTip, % GetKeyState("NumLock", "T")` always prints `1`. Anyway, I could still settle to use `Pause` to trigger an internal variable and use this instead of the `NumLock` state as a workaround. Could you help me with that? (Keep both solutions for reference.)

Comment: Okay, this is weird. I am not sure why it is registered as `Pause` since it still emits code `045`, which is, according to the various tables I found a code for `NUM_LOCK` https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start-win_general/what-are-these-mysterious-fnkey-functions/709cf845-c84e-4bd2-a3d5-e0c656a37ac7

Comment: Try changing the `NumLock` in the code for `Pause`, if `Fn+B` is change the `Pause` state, it should work.

I apologize for the delay in answering..